# improper token has been passed discord.py

Tags: python

**So i am actually trying to make a bot which would send embed to  the discord server, orginally wont send, i would do the command nd it will in return send embed message in the server. But i keep getting error when i try to run the bot. Btw i am using Pycharm, anyways have a look.**

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import asyncio
```

```
bot_prefix = "`"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)


@bot.event
async def on_event():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("---------")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def embed(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Blog Post # 2",
            url="https://darksiderclan2.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/4/7/114760003/published/battle.png?1510944203/n",
            color=0xffff00,
            description="Aquí hay una segunda publicación de blog para su sitio web/n",
            )
        await bot.say(embed=embed)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**So that was my code, now the error i am getting is:**

```
`C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:/Users/Default.Default-PC/Desktop/Chief Bot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 252, in static_login
    data = yield from self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 212, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: UNAUTHORIZED (status code: 401): 401: Unauthorized
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Default.Default-PC/Desktop/Chief Bot.py", line 27, in 
    bot.run('WPUi5O1UAxfQiiK2GDz9cktDO82ApySM')
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 567, in run
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 487, in _silence_gathered
    fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 474, in start
    yield from self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 352, in login
    yield from self.http.static_login(token, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 256, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from e
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

Process finished with exit code 1`

**Please tell me what is problem? i didnt used to get this error before when i used to make bots.**

Answer (score 8):

I know this Thread is old but for anyone still searching for an answer to this (since it's the first thing that pops up when you search for it)

He probably used the client token instead of the bot token, to get the bot token you'll have to go to the Discord Delevoper Portal and click the "Bot" tab on the left hand side, then click on "click to reveal token" under the input section for the Bot's name, copy and insert into your code. Worked for me.

Comment: I think it would be good if you showed what part of the code you changed.

Comment: you change the "bot.run('TOKEN')" line (last line in his code) to the BOT token, not the user token (explained above). What he did was probably: "bot.run('<USERTOKEN>')" instead of "bot.run('<BOTTOKEN>')" obviously you'll have to replace "<BOTTOKEN>" with the actual token.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the client token? Let's say I simply just want to save all messages from a specific server / channel to a text file. Do I have to make a bot account in that case?